# INSERT INTO Syntax error c#,Access

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I get "INSERT INTO Syntax error" int my query,I have no idea why.
(The connection to Access is in another class).

```
    public void InsertOrder(Order Item) // add new order
    {
        string cmdStr = "INSERT INTO [Order] (CostumerID,ProID,ProName,ProPrice,Comments,Discount,Color,Size,Quantity,OrdertDate) VALUES (@costumerID,@proID,@proName,@proPrice,@comments,@discount,@proColor,@proSize,@quantity,@orderDate)";
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(cmdStr))
        {

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@costumerID", Item.CostumerID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proID", Item.ProId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proName", Item.ProName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proPrice", Item.ProPrice);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", Item.Comments);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount", Item.Discount);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proColor", Item.ProColor);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proSize", Item.ProSize);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", Item.Quantity);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderDate", Item.OrderDate);

            base.ExecuteSimpleQuery(command);
        }

    }
```

Any help please?
Thanks!

Comment: You have asked 8 questions and gotten 11 answers, but accepted none of them.  As explained in the [Tour] accepting answers and (later) upvoting helps other users find good answers.  Please, take a moment to take the [Tour] and click the Checkmark on some of the past answers  you have gotten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at this page: [Reserved Words in MSAccess](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe?CorrelationId=cb314af3-a2b5-4bda-82ee-de1c1dc90159&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010030643)

You will notice that SIZE is a reserved keyword, so if you really can't change that name and still want to use it in your code, you need to enclose it in square brackets

```
   string cmdStr = @"INSERT INTO [Order] 
          (CostumerID,ProID,ProName,ProPrice,Comments,
           Discount,Color,[Size],Quantity,OrdertDate) 
           VALUES (@costumerID,@proID,@proName,@proPrice,@comments,
                   @discount,@proColor,@proSize,@quantity,@orderDate)";
```